# Relative paths in custom component library

Tags: javascript, css, relative-path, custom-component, shadow-dom

I have project with structure that looks like this

```
-client
----index.html
----index.ts
-core
----controls
--------myControl.html
--------myControl.ts
----css
--------common.css
```

myControl.html contains definition of custom component that is registered via shadow dom.
 in its template imports common.css that is part of "core" library:

```
<template id="t">
    <style>
        @import url('../css/common.css');
    ....
    </style>
    ....
</template>
<script>
  (function() {
      var importDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument; // importee

      var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

      proto.createdCallback = function() 
      {
          // get template in import
          var template = importDoc.querySelector('#t');

          // import template into
          var clone = document.importNode(template.content, true);

          var root = this.createShadowRoot();
          root.appendChild(clone);

          var control = this;

          System.import('core/controls/myControl').then(function(m)
          {
              var t = new m.myControl(control.shadowRoot);
          });
      };

      document.registerElement('my-control', {prototype: proto});
  })();
</script>
```

Now when I use my-control on the index.html the browser complains that it cannot import common.css. Because it search for it using path relative to index.html, not relative to its originall location. I understand this is logical because we have created shadow dom from the script that runs in context of index.html.

My question is: how should I develop my-control custom component that is part of 'core' library that can be reused/distributed in different places and still correctly reference resources like css/images/etc that are also part of the 'core' library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you use absolute URLs?**

Post /deep/ deprecation same as you, css @injects is the way we have been applying a common styling across our components.

**But how to identify path of common style?**

First to give some context, we host our components in a single vulcanized html file and clients use html imports to use it in their applications.
Now in this imports.html we have included a small script which identifies its own URL using `document.currentScript.ownerDocument.baseURI` and since we know the path of common css relative of imports.html, we construct this url on the fly and inject constructed style tags containing css @imports inside templates.

That way, when component gets *updated*(when shadow-root gets attached to it) it makes a call to download common.css(since it knows the absolute url) and uses it inside shadow dom.

So, to summarize don't hardcode style tag with css @import inside template construct it based on your current url of imported html and inject it inside template.

something like this perhaps:

```
//URL of your html import or script being executed.
var host = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.baseURI;
//splice and dice your host url to get protocol and base url
...
// let's say it is proto and base
var cssURL = proto + base + '/core/css/common.css'
// construct a style tag here with css imports.
// Since you have access to document-fragment coming with html import
// find template and inject this style tag inside it.
// Remember to inject it at top :)
```