# Polymer 1.0 - Apply dynamic style to custom element after ajax response

Tags: polymer, shadow-dom

I have a custom element that has two categories of styles, static and dynamic. The static styles exist in the module `<dom-module><style>...</style></dom-module>` but the dynamic styles need to live in their own stylesheets and then get loaded if necessary.

The custom element will have a few styles with the syntax `color: var(--dynamic-element-color)` then after some ajax stuff determines a client I will grab that client's stylesheet and include it in some fashion to update the mixin styles...maybe via `@import url(client-1.html)` combined with `Polymer.updateStyles()` if necessary.

I attempted this via 2 methods:

1)Within the custom element's method - some form of this worked in Chrome but no where else:

```
ready: function() {
    this.determineClientStyle('test');
},
determineClientStyle: function(client) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = 'import';
    link.href = '/elements/'+client+'/linus.html';
    var beforeNode = Polymer.dom(this.root).childNodes[0];
    Polymer.dom(this.root).insertBefore(link, beforeNode);
}
```

2)Within index.html - worked in Chrome and FF but not Safari or my phone's "internet" browser:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
    function applyClientTheme(client) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'import';
        link.href = client+'.html';
        Polymer.dom(document.head).appendChild(link);
    }
    applyClientTheme('theme');
});
```

[Here is an example project on github.](https://github.com/tehaaron/PolymerTesting)

My real project has numerous custom elements all of which will have styles with `var(--some-style)` and I hope to load a single import that fulfills them all on a per client basis.

I have yet to be successful with what @Abhinav mentions below...either that or I am interpreting  it incorrectly or just doing it wrong.

What is the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here :

#### 1. Style leaking on the page

You don't want your style to leak on to the page but most probably you are not using shadow dom, because starting from Polymer 1.0 [shady dom](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html) is the default which doesn't provide style encapsulation.
You can force polymer to use shadow dom where it is supported by tweaking global polymer [settings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html).

```
<script>
    window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {};
    window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
</script>
```

#### 2. Using external stylesheet inside shadow dom

You can use css @imports inside shadow dom to load external stylesheet.
When components are available on the page, along with `client` identifier, you can *inject* these style tags inside your local dom.
If you are using html imports to bring in your components on page, you can include a small script in your html which will contain code to inject style tags inside templates.
something like this perhaps:

```
//If you are using html imports to bring in your components on page.
//doc will contain html which is being imported.
var doc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;

// Fetch template from doc
var myTemplate = doc.querySelector('template#myTemplate');
var cssURL = '/elements/'+client+'/dynamic_style_1.css';
// construct a style tag here with css @imports which contain above css url.
// Since you have access to template in myTemplate
// inject this style tag inside it.
// Since it is a css @import, Remember to inject it at top(using insertBefore)
```

I have written few descriptive answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32941101/4788782) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915096/relative-paths-in-custom-component-library/32956340#32956340) on the topic.
Hope it helps.

---

#### Edit

**`document.currentScript.ownerDocument` returns document ***of which*** script is currently being executed.**

Now, there are 2 places where your component might exist.

1. Host(Current) document
   In this case, `document.currentScript.ownerDocument` will return the current document from which you can fetch the template. But you don't really need this here because you can rather do a `document.querySelector` directly and then append a style tag to it or do whatever you want.
2. Imported document
   Now this is a bummer since your template isn't present on the current page so `document.querySelector` can't fetch you that.
   So, there are two ways you can append a style tag to it now, which will differ based on **where** you want to do this operation.

**a. Ready method:** you want to do in ready method when your client identifier is present.

Very well, you don't need `document.currentScript.ownerDocument` here either because you can just query for your link tag and fetch contents from it using *import* property.
Something like this:

```
<link id="myImport" rel="import" href="my-components.html">
```

---

```
//This is what goes inside ready method
var linkTag = document.querySelector('#myImport');
var importContent = linkTag.import;
var myTemplate = importContents.querySelector('#myTemplate');
//Yayy!! You have your template. Now go ahead and inject a style tag into it.
```

**b. Imported HTML:** Nope! I want to do it even before that. Actually I want to do it when my contents are being imported on the page.

Okies. Only option you have here is... wait for it...  Yup, you guessed it. `document.currentScript.ownerDocument`.
Quoting this nice [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/) on HTML imports.

> Imports are not in the main document. They're satellite to it. However,
>   your import can still act on the main page even though the main
>   document reigns supreme. An import can access its own DOM and/or the
>   DOM of the page that's importing it.
>
> The script inside the import references the imported document
>   (document.currentScript.ownerDocument)

I hope your use case lies in one of the three possibilities mentioned above.
At the end, your shadow root should contain a style tag with a css @import which should point to correct location of your css file.
If that is true, style will load on the page and will be applied **only** inside your shadow root.

Comment: I do not follow your descriptive answers. Can you provide some concrete code on how you would inject addition stylesheets into your custom elements?

Comment: I have updated my answer with code snippet. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32956340/4788782) is one more answer which provides more details if needed.

Comment: Can you look at my updated code snippet in the question and tell me if this is the right place and way to go about it? This ready method belongs to the custom element that will consume the style. Additionally, I can see that `style` is getting added as a child node of `myTemplate` but I am not positive that, that is what I want.

Comment: I also noticed that document.currentScript.ownerDocument doesnt work if the custom element code is in a separate file and being imported.

Comment: Your last edit was something which I was suggesting. Did it work?

I have updated my answer with your query regarding `document.currentScript.ownerDocument`

Comment: Both of the attempts I made above worked in Chrome but so far nothing is working in Safari on OSX or iOS. I will experiment with your latest suggestions tonight/tomorrow. I really appreciate your input!

Comment: One other question, do these solutions rely on setting `window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow'`? Because that is something I did not do as I opted to stick with the default shady dom behavior.

Comment: Oh yes. That is the crucial bit because otherwise you are using shady dom, which doesn't provide style encapsulation. In other words, your style will leak on to the page.

Comment: For fixing issues in browsers which don't support HTML imports(or, webcomponents in general), read [this](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/html-imports/). To summarize, in browsers other than chrome you'll have to use `document._currentScript.ownerDocument` (note the underscore).